jinja2 how to use "if not loop last" with nested loops
I have:
a = [a1, a2]
b = [b1, b2]

I want
{
{a1, b1},
{a1, b2},
{a2, b1},
{a2, b2}
}

My code doesn't work because the "if not loop last" consider the second loop and supress too many commas
{
{% for a in as %}
    {% for b in bs %}
        {a,b} {{"," if not loop last}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
}

I get
{
{a1, b1},
{a1, b2}
{a2, b1},
{a2, b2}
}

Is there a way to tell jinja2 something like "if not BOTH loop last"?

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/stable/templates/#for: "The loop variable always refers to the closest (innermost) loop. If we have more than one level of loops, we can rebind the variable loop by writing {% set outer_loop = loop %} after the loop that we want to use recursively. Then, we can call it using {{ outer_loop(...) }}" - so you will probably have to employ a similar strategy here.

{
{% for a in as %}
    {% set outer_loop = loop %}
    {% for b in bs %}
        {a,b} {{"," if not loop last or not outer_loop.last}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
}

